# How to specify parentOrganization for my Organization?

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets, json-ld

Here is my schema:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "addressLocality": "California, USA",
    "postalCode": "92867",
    "streetAddress": "1636 W Collins Ave"
  },
  "telephone": "18008931107",
  "name": "Mesa Garage Doors",
  "parentOrganization": {
    "name": "Overhead Garage Doors Store"
  }
}
</script>
```

If you go test this schema on Google’s schema checker, I get this error:

> The property `parentOrganization` is not recognized by Google for an object of type `Organization`.

I am using this `parentOrganization` property from Schema.org: http://schema.org/parentOrganization

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** The below answer is for version 2.0 of Schema.org. Since version 2.1 ([see commit](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/535)), `parentOrganization` can be used for `Organization`, too.

---

The [`parentOrganization` property](http://schema.org/parentOrganization) (which was previously named [`branchOf`](http://schema.org/branchOf)) is only defined for [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness), not for the broader [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization).

When using `Organization`, the only available properties for relationships to another `Organization` are:

- [`department`](http://schema.org/department)
- [`member`](http://schema.org/member)/[`memberOf`](http://schema.org/memberOf)
- [`subOrganization`](http://schema.org/subOrganization)

(As of [version 2.0](http://schema.org/docs/releases.html#v2.0).)

Comment: Note: I filed [an issue](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/535 "GitHub: Domain of parentOrganization: Organization instead of LocalBusiness?") if the domain could be changed from `LocalBusiness` to `Organization`.

Comment: Update: It [got committed](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/535#issuecomment-110038206), so it will likely be available with the next Schema.org release.

Comment: Looks like it is now part of Organization: https://schema.org/Organization

Comment: https://validator.schema.org/ still throws an error when I use it with either `LocalBusiness` or `Organization`... Any ideas why that's still an issue? Is the validator out of date?